# Several optional components use same registry setting

Tags: wix, wix3.5

Our installer has several optional but mutually exclusive components, but each uses the same registry setting to store a path.  We are now facing the problem that some users wish to change the component, deselecting one and selecting another.  We see that the registry setting is deleted.

The uninstalled component registry setting is marked for action "Absent" as we would expect, but the new component is first set to be "Local" again as we would expect, but then reset to "Null". In the log extract below, `InDesignCS4RegistryKeys` should be removed and `InDesignCS5RegistryKeys` should be installed.

> MSI (s) (34:F0) [11:44:08:928]: Component: InDesignCS5RegistryKeys;
>   Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local MSI (s) (34:00)
>   [11:44:36:200]: Component: InDesignCS4RegistryKeys; Installed: Local; 
>   Request: Absent;   Action: Absent MSI (s) (34:00) [11:44:36:201]:
>   Component: InDesignCS5RegistryKeys; Installed: Absent;   Request:
>   Null;   Action: Null

The other components for InDesignCS4 are removed and InDesignCS5 added.

Any ideas as to how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Users don't select and deselect components, they select and deselect features.

If you have 3 components now,  move the registry data to a 4th component.  Associate the first 3 components to their own feature and associate the 4th component to all three features.

Put checks in your UI and Execute sequence to enforce that the features are mutually exclusive.

If you want to have 1 feature and drive the component selection based on a component condition, do the same thing but on the 4th component either have no condition or have Component1 Expression OR Component2 Expression OR Component3 Expression.